# Fill DataTable from LinqDataSource

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

How do I obtain a DataTable from a LinqDataSource?

I have found the DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable() method, but can't work out how to use this with a LinqDataSource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
    IEnumerable<DataRow> query = ...;
    DataTable.DataSource = query.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

Comment: With query being a linq query, but how do I do that with a LinqDataSource?